# i want the code to wait for previous line to be done before continuing

Tags: python, streamlit, google-news

hi i'm using streamlit to take input from user and using GoogleNews module i'm searching news related to the input text and storing them in a variable "result_0"..
but i want the bellow steps to finish before continuing

```
googlenews.search(inputt.iloc[0,0])
googlenews.get_news(inputt.iloc[0,0])
result_0 = googlenews.page_at(1)
```

but in fact whats happening is that the system is going directly to the next line which is :

```
if len(result_0) == 0:
```

and its always true because result didn't get the chance to load the news from previous step i tried using time.sleep() function but i'm not sure how long does the step take since the number of news depends on the input text

Comment: Are `search()` and `get_news()` desynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are using the [GoogleNews](https://github.com/Iceloof/GoogleNews) package.
Here is the code to show news by term in a streamlit app using [GoogleNews](https://github.com/Iceloof/GoogleNews):

```
import streamlit as st
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews

# add app title
st.title('Google news')
st.markdown("""---""")

# get user input for seraching news
user_input = st.sidebar.text_input("Enter news term")

state = st.sidebar.button("Get News!")

if state:
    # get news
    googlenews = GoogleNews()
    googlenews.get_news(user_input)
    news = googlenews.results()
    if news:
        for i in news:            
            st.markdown(f"**{i['title']}**")
            st.write(f"Published Date - {i['date']}")
            st.markdown(f"[Article Link]({i['link']})")
            st.markdown("---")
            
    else:
        st.write("No news for this term")
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Also I would suggest you use the [GNews](https://github.com/ranahaani/GNews/) package instead because it has better functionality. Here is the code to show news by term in a streamlit app using [GNews](https://github.com/ranahaani/GNews/):

```
import streamlit as st
from gnews import GNews

# add app title
st.title('Google news')
st.markdown("""---""")

# get user input for seraching news
user_input = st.sidebar.text_input("Enter news term")

state = st.sidebar.button("Get News!")

if state:
    # get news
    news = GNews().get_news(user_input)
    if news:
        for i in news:
            st.markdown(f"**{i['title']}**")
            st.write(f"Published Date - {i['published date']}")
            st.write(i["description"])
            st.markdown(f"[Article Link]({i['url']})")
            st.markdown("""---""")
    else:
        st.write("No news for this term")
```

Here is the output:
[image]